# Android: sqlite: cursor: getColumnIndex

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, normalize

I've got a fairly complicated query (multiple joins) on a normalized sqlite database. The query does a `SELECT *` to enable some automated attribute selection logic (so I can't eliminate the "*")

The problem I am having is that my result set contains multiple columns with the same attribute name. For example, one attribute common to each table in the query is "_id". When I go to call `"cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")"` the value returned is always the index of the last `"_id"` attribute in the result set column list (i.e. not the one I want). I'd love to be able to use my SQL alias prefixes like  `cursor.getColumnIndex("A._id")` but that is not working.

**QUESTIONs**

- It appears that `cursor.getColumnIndex(AttributeName)` returns the index of the last "AttributeName". Can anyone confirm this?
- Also, any suggestions on how return the index of the 1st attribute with "AttributeName"? or better the Xth attribute having "AttributeName"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT _id as myID, * FROM myTable
```

This means the `_id` field will appear twice for each table in your results, but one of the two columns will have a unique name which should enable you to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't mention anything about what you need to do, so I am assuming it cannot be done.

However, you say

> The query does a SELECT * to enable some automated attribute selection
>   logic (so I can't eliminate the "*")

What is this 'automated attribute selection logic' you speak of? Why do you require this?

Comment: its part of a survey data collection system - the logic assists in  dynamically packaging appropriate (each device may have different rules for determining what "appropiate" is...) data for transmission back to a central data store. This logic is not something that I have liberty to modify...

Comment: Ah that is unfortunate, have you trying prefixing with the complete table name? Such as users._id ?

Answer (score -3):

An oder solution is:

```
"SELECT tableName.columnName FROM tableName"
```

and then do the same with:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("tableName.columnName");
```

This is what MS-Access does. You can create a query and then see the generated SQL code (simply going to 'view' menu and selecting 'SQL view' from your query dessign window)

Comment: As author said, android sqlite wrapped doesn't support alias prefixes.